# How to compare speed of graphics cards in Windows desktop environment?

Tags: graphics-card, integrated-graphics

I use Windows 7 and Intel Core i3 CPU with integrated graphics. My problem is that it eats valuable system RAM for display. I can replace it with an old PCIe Radeon X700, so all system RAM will be usable for applications. The question is if an old Radeon X700 is comparable in W7 desktop speed to a new integrated i3 graphics. Are there any test programs which compare the speed of graphic cards in Windows 7 desktop environment (i.e. no Direct3D games, just Windows desktop)?

(According to Tomshardware, Radeon X700 is probably even faster than Core i3 in 3D. But there are no native WDDM 1.1 W7 drivers for X700, only WDDM 1.0 Vista drivers are available.)

Comment: Why not use the Windows Experience Index numbers for the comparison?  Of course you'll have to install the Radeon card to derive its numbers.  The Vista drivers will probably work for Win7.

Comment: Tested: The Vista drivers (WDDM 1.0) work perfectly.